# Do I need to use UseHsts

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a simple question; Do I need the `app.UseHsts()` middleware if my app is running behind an nginx server which itself is configured to handle https?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it depends what you mean by *handle https*? If nginx is setting your `Strict-Transport-Security` header correctly, then you don't *need* `app.UseHsts()`. Aside from that, there is the argument that setting it on the ASP.NET Core is safer (it ensures it's set without relying on e.g. nginx being configured to do it), but that specifically is more of opinion-based decision.

Comment: You need `UseHsts` if you want to use HSTS for the communication between your application and your reverse proxy. Whether that is good or not, or necessary at all, depends on your environment and cannot really be answered in an answer on SO.

Comment: By 'nginx server configured to handle https', do you mean the nginx enforcing hsts on the block which configure the proxy pass? If yes, then most of the time, you don't need it. 

Depending on the use case, adding additional encryption between nginx and your localhost-only app, might be redundant and wasting compute resources.

Answer (score 0):

May be a late answer, still answering for other guys who might be looking out.

No. In fact if you look at the documentation for core Hsts (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), the suggestion is to uncheck 'Configure for HTTPS' for development. Introduce UseHsts in the final stages of development.